# Can eddy currents be extremely reduced?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it possible to create a certain design of a conductor to reduce eddy currents greatly? So that  the magnetic "breaking" can be reduced?

Is it even possible for the force generated by the eddy currents to become negligible?

Comment: Yes; here's [a demo experiment showing this effect](http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~scidemos/ElectricityMagnetism/EddyCurrentPendulum/EddyCurrentPendulum.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can **cut into** the metal a couple of times, **orthogonal** to the direction of the eddy currents.

So they **just can not flow any longer**;, that also prevents the **secondary effects** of the eddy currents, like the **drag**.

Note that the piece of metal has still about the same shape,

Comment: But broken down greatly so that eddy currents are some-what not induced.

Comment: This is why you see transformer cores made of sliced pieces of metal instead of one metallic chunk.

Comment: Makes sense, slice it up! Better.

Answer (score 2):

Eddy currents result from an imposed time-changing magnetic field. The magnitude of $-dB/dt$ induced circulating current densities $J$ in a specimen of conductor will typically be proportional to the mean cross-sectional diameter. As $I^2R$ losses obviously go as the square of such induced current densities, a typical strategy to reduce overall loss is braiding - many smaller diameter wires with adequate insulation between each strand. That will reduce the net loss by approximately the ratio of unbraided to braided wire diameters. Lamination is an alternate strategy - it's commonly how eddy-current losses in low frequency transformer iron cores are minimized.

Comment: But, will it be reduced to the point that the effect is negligible?

Comment: Apart from what has already been outlined, one could increase resistivity of the conductor. Which is sort of self-defeating. Maxwell's equations, in particular here the Maxwell-Faraday law tend to dictate what can and cannot be achieved. Obviously if the configuration permits it, minimizing exposure to the offending time-varying $B$ field(s) is all that remains as possible option.

Comment: True, the idea in mind is to accelerate a conductor in a magnetic field, at very high velocities, and would want to reduced the eddy current's magnetic breaking effect, best option i guess is just breaking the conductor up into the smallest pieces possible to reduce it so that it could be negligible.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like 'rail gun' research. If so just Google the term and follow the leads. The basics principle is simple but detail is everything when it comes to practicality.